# Button get position in activity from adapter

Tags: android, button, android-activity, position, adapter

I want to set position onClick Button where I have declared in Adapter, but I don't know how to set the position in Activity.

This is My Adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoViewHolder holder, final int position) {holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mContext instanceof PhotoPicker) {
            ((PhotoPicker) mContext).tambahFoto(position);

        }
    }
});}
```

I wanna call in my function in Activity like this

```
public void tambahFoto(int position) {


    count = Integer.parseInt(tampilan.getText().toString());

    if(count > 1) {
        jumlahFoto = jumlahFoto + 1;
        photo_cropAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        count++;
        tampilan.setText(""+count);
        jum.setText(jumlahFoto+"/ "+dataProduct.getMaxQty()+" Photo");

    }

    }
```

But how can I set the Button's position? Can you help me?

Comment: mContext is an Activity or Context?

Comment: in 'tambahFoto' function, you are not using 'position' anywhere.

Comment: just a Context @ShubhamChauhan, because I don't how to set the position, can you show me the way to make it?

Comment: instead of Context just pass that Activity and then this will work fine.

Comment: actually what do you want to achieve? do you want to reorder the photo list in the photo picker or what?